# jquery getting options text from different select ids in a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the code below if options from both color_select and size_select are selected, only the latest selected option is logged only(e.g either red or small is logged if both are selected depending whichever is selected later). How to log options from both the select(color_select and size_select) on change in one function when option from either of the select is changed (i.e log both red and small if both are selected)?

```
<h6>Choose Color</h6>
<select id="color_select" name="color" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
</select>

<h6>Choose Size</h6>
<select id="size_select" name="size" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
</select>

   $('#color_select','#size_select').on('change' , function() {
    // Code here
    var $this = $(this);
   if($this.find('option:selected').index() !== 0){

       text = $this.find('option:selected').text();
       console.log(text);
   }     
}).change()
```

Comment: It’s `$('#color_select, #size_select')`. `$('#color_select','#size_select')` has a very different meaning.

Comment: Tried both $('#color_select, #size_select') and $('#color_select, #size_select'). $('#color_select','#size_select'). None of the two gave desired result. What I want is if red and small are selected both should be logged. Now if the color is changed to blue and the size is kept unchanged, then blue and small should be logged

Comment: `this` in the event handler is the `select` that changed.  The event handler doesn't know anything about the original selector, so don't know that the event will be fired for two `select`s.  You need to read the values inside the event handler, eg `console.log($("#color_select").val() + ' ' + $("#size_select").val())`

Comment: It works but for some reason I want to use $(this).

Comment: $('select') can be used for all the select tags in a page. Is it possible to find the values of select tags with particular ids and then log those values in one function?